# dropdown event/callback in combo-box in pyqt4

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt4

is there a callback or event for dropdown in pyqt4 combo box? Just like `self.connect(self.ui.combobox,SIGNAL("activated(int)"),self.refresh`

Comment: You mean a signal that is emitted when the dropdown menu is shown? I.e., when the user clicks on the combobox?

Comment: yes, when the user clicks on the combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QCombobox uses a QAbstractItemView (QListView by default) to display the dropdown items (accessible via the [`view()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcombobox.html#view) property).
I am not aware of any signal for that purpose.

But you can set an eventFilter that will do the trick by using [`installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the view of the combobox and implement the [`eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#eventFilter) method:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class ShowEventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, filteredObj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            print "Popup Showed !"
            # do whatever you want
        return QtCore.QObject.eventFilter(self, filteredObj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    cb = QtGui.QComboBox()
    cb.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c'])

    eventFilter = ShowEventFilter()
    cb.view().installEventFilter(eventFilter)
    cb.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
```

signal (inherited from QWidget)?

Comment: maybe is not an answer