# QComboBox click event

Tags: python, events, drop-down-menu, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have been trying to get a `QComboBox` in PyQt5 to become populated from a database table. The problem is trying to find a method that recognizes a click event on it.

In my GUI, my combo-box is initially empty, but upon clicking on it I wish for the click event to activate my method for communicating to the database and populating the drop-down list. It seems so far that there is no built-in event handler for a click-event for the combo-box. I am hoping that I am wrong on this. I hope someone will be able to tell me that there is a way to do this.

The best article I could find on my use-case here is from this link referring to PyQt4 `QComboBox`:

- [dropdown event/callback in combo-box in pyqt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021768/dropdown-event-callback-in-combo-box-in-pyqt4)

I also found another link that contains a nice image of a `QComboBox`.
The first element seems to be a label followed by a list:

- [Catch mouse button pressed signal from QComboBox popup menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186779/catch-mouse-button-pressed-signal-from-qcombobox-popup-menu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override the [showPopup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#showPopup) method to achieve this, which will work no matter how the drop-down list is opened (i.e. via the mouse, keyboard, or shortcuts):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    popupAboutToBeShown = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def showPopup(self):
        self.popupAboutToBeShown.emit()
        super(ComboBox, self).showPopup()

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.combo = ComboBox(self)
        self.combo.popupAboutToBeShown.connect(self.populateConbo)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

    def populateConbo(self):
        if not self.combo.count():
            self.combo.addItems('One Two Three Four'.split())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, for your particular use-case, I think a better solution might be to set a [QSqlQueryModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) on the combo-box, so that the items are updated from the database automatically.

Comment: HI ekhumoro, Really appreciate your input here. It seems that your solution is the closest to what I would be looking for. I was not aware of this property, it makes sense, I never noticed this before:void QComboBox::showPopup() ,  so thanks for making me aware of this. I will this as the answer to my question. Thanks so much ekhumoro!!!

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative Solution I :**

We can use frame click, the code is to be used in the container of the combo box (windows/dialog/etc.)

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("Hello world !")
```

or

```
def mousePressEvent():
        print("Hello world !")
```

**Alternative Solution II :**

We could connect a handler to the pressed signal of the combo's view

```
    self.uiComboBox.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
    ...

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.uiComboBox.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        print("Do something with the selected item")
```

Comment: Hi intika, this looks interesting, definitely a different perspective, did not think about : Combo View(). I need to look into this, to understand this, this Alternative Solution 2.

Comment: But I don't know about this thing you refer to as using "Frame Click". I only see code for mousePressEvent. So I am not understanding this one.

Comment: On the first alternative what i mean is : if in your application the user have to click on the windows (not the combo) for a reason or an other... you can then intercept that click and do what you want... 
also an other alternative you could hide/disable the combo box and force the user to do something to display it and use that event to do whatever you want :)

Answer (score -3):

Why would you want to populate it when it's activated rather than when the window is loaded?

I am currently developing an application with PySide (another Python binding for the Qt framework), and I populate my comboboxes in the mainwindow class `__init__` function, which seems to be the way to go, judging by many examples.

Look at the example code under "QCombobox" over at [Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/widgets2/).

Comment: Hi, I understand what you are saying. But my database maybe empty in the beginning, so the drop-down will not be populate at all when the user first uses the application. The table in the database in the beginning will need to be populated via another source by the user. So I need for it to be populated later in the life-cycle of the program. So I cannot use when window loads event.

Comment: @Palu QCombobox have a signal called "Highlighted" which is emitted when the cursor hovers the QCombobox (as per what I've read).

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it might get the job done? 

Otherwise, would it be possible to make a function that detects when a new DB entry occurs and just add the new items as they come, rather than doing it when the QCombobox is is clicked?

Comment: Hi Pkarls, that is an interesting idea about a function detects when new entry occurs. I will think about that. I just find it odd that it seems that the PyQt people did not think of this basic event for a ComboBox.

Comment: @Palu Yeah, I'm with you on that one.